# Extract data from DBpedia (connecting sparql endpoint from java)

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia, extract

I need to extract some data from DBpedia. I know that I can use http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ and write a query there and then see a result. But is there any tool/class to connect DBpedia endpoint from java, write query in a code and then get result in a file?

Comment: I can't believe that you couldn't find a tool or API for Java via using a search engine of your choice ... moreover, this question is supposed to be off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several, of which [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/) and [Eclipse RDF4J](https://rdf4j.org/) are probably the most well-known.

Here's a simple example executing a SPARQL query on the DBPedia endpoint from Java and printing the result, using RDF4J:

```
  Repository endpoint = new SPARQLRepository("http://dbpedia.org/sparql");
  try (RepositoryConnection conn = endpoint.getConnection()) {
        TupleQueryResult result = conn.prepareTupleQuery("SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10").evaluate();
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

To get the result in a file is of course also possible. I suggest you have a look at the project documentation to find out more about the possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for help.